# Can I exchange data from a smartphone and in parallel quick charge it with an ic?

Tags: pcb, design

I am trying to exchange data between a smartphone and an microcontroller, also in parallel i would like to quick charge the smartphone with a commercial ic. The usb protocol is 2.0. Can i exchange data simultaneously with the quick charge protocol?
This will be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Quick answer: yes, that is what USB is good at doing. It has power cables and data cables. It can talk to your PC while your PC is charging it at the same time.

Comment: I know that for a simple charge, but this happens also in the quick charge?

Comment: By quick charge do you mean Qualcomm Quick Charge? Or simply 5V 2A USB power?

Comment: With Qualcomm Quick Charge!

Comment: AFAIK Qualcomm Quick Charge uses the data lines to signal the charger to deliver the requested voltage, meaning you can't Quick Charge and transfer data at the same time. Let me double check and dig up a reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up to the Qualcomm's solution because the 5V 2A usb power doesn't apply in the usb 2.0.

Comment: Well that's true but Qualcomm QC also technically violates the USB 2.0 standard so ;)

Comment: In this way i will add a control switch to change between quick charge and normal usb 2.0 operation for the data transfer

Comment: Yes that sounds like the way to go if your device needs to do both "in parallel".

Comment: Keep in mind though that QC 2.0 voltage can go as high as 12V so if your MCU or other components are using VBUS make sure they can handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page on the QC 2.0 protocol](http://www.hackvlog.com/2016/12/bitbanging-quick-charge-2.html) the differential data pair is used to request the desired voltage from the QC capable charger, meaning you cannot transfer data through the USB interface while you are quick charging. To use the data lines you must first exit Quick Charge mode by tying D- to below 0.325V, and wait until VBUS returns to 5V.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to not use usb for data. Use Bluetooth or wifi with your microcontroller for the data.

Most phones lack a way to transfer data over usb to a microcontroller easily, and trying to charge the phone at the same time is even harder.